# How to handle long running jobs with System.Cron.Schedule?

Tags: haskell, job-scheduling

I'm trying to learn Haskell.  As a first stab, I'm looking to write a daemon that periodically runs a backup job for me.

I'm using [`System.Cron.Schedule`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cron-0.6.1/docs/System-Cron-Schedule.html) to do the scheduling for me and running the [`restic`](https://restic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) executable to do the backup.

As this is a backup job, it can take a log time to run, to prevent the next scheduled backup from running when the previous one hasn't been completed yet, I want to make sure that I can only have 1 instance of the job running.  How do prevent a long running job from being run again?

As an simplified example, how do I make the following not spawn another job every minute until the existing job is done?

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
       tids <- execSchedule $ do
           addJob doBackup "* * * * *"
       print tids

doBackup :: IO ()
doBackup = do
    putStrLn "Backing up system..."
    threadDelay 70000000
    putStrLn "Backup finished"
```

Comment: You may want to post some code - solving this really depends on what you've got so far. Glancing at the `System.Cron.Schedule` docs, it looks like you will likely be doing a fair bit of work in the `IO` monad (or something that is `MonadIO`). You could use an [`MVar`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html#t:MVar) to prevent a job from starting until the previous has finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the implementation of @Alec's suggestion. This creates an `MVar ()` (which is basically a semaphore), and then every time your job runs, it checks whether the `MVar` is free before it continues, and dies otherwise.

```
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do sem <- newMVar () -- starts off not taken
          tids <- execSchedule $ addJob (doBackup sem) "* * * * *" -- do x = x
          print tids
          forever $ threadDelay maxBound
       -- all threads exit when main exits. ^ stops that from happening
       -- Control.Monad.forever x = let loop = x >> loop in loop
       -- don't do forever $ return () unless you want a CPU-nomming busyloop


doBackup :: MVar () -> IO ()
doBackup sem = do res <- tryTakeMVar sem
               -- gives Nothing if the sem is taken and Just () if it isn't
               -- you DON'T want takeMVar, since that'll block until sem is
               -- free, essentially queueing the jobs up instead of
               -- canceling the ones that run too early.
                  case res of
                       Nothing -> return () -- already taken? do nothing
                       Just () -> do putStrLn "Backing up system..."
                                     threadDelay 70000000
                                     putStrLn "Backup finished"
                                     putMVar sem () -- release the lock
```

FYI: this is not exception-safe. See the implementation of `withMVar` for pointers in that direction.

Comment: In real code I would suggest abstracting this functionality into its own unit, e.g. `oneAtATime :: MVar () -> IO () -> IO ()`